# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, google-chrome, vim

I tried to install Google chrome on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I just followed the manual installation procedure mentioned in this [link](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-google-chrome-ubuntu-12-04/) and finally when I was about to install the .deb package of google-chrome, something went wrong and chrome didn't install successfully and unfortunately after that I started noticing some dependency issues with any other installation.

I read through some posts and did 
`sudo do-release-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get -f upgrade` so on and still nothing has resolved the problem, and it got even worse. For example when I try to install `vim` am noticing the errors below:

```
sudo apt-get -f install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-xapian-index : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 compizconfig-settings-manager : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 hplip-data : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus-table : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 landscape-client-ui-install : Depends: python:any
 libgcj-common : Depends: python:any
 python-appindicator : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-apport : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-apt : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-aptdaemon : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-cairo : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-chardet : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-configglue : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dateutil : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dbus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-debtagshw : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-defer : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dirspec : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-egenix-mxdatetime : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-egenix-mxtools : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gi : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gobject-2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gst0.10 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-launchpadlib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.restfulclient : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.uri : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-libproxy : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-libxml2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-louis : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lxml : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-mako : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-markupsafe : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-notify : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-oauth : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-openssl : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pexpect : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7)
                        Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-problem-report : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pycurl : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyinotify : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-qt4 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-serial : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-sip : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-software-properties : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-core : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-web : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-wadllib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-xapian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-xdg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-xkit : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zeitgeist : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zope.interface : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 scons : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 software-center : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
                   Recommends: xz-utils (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614-1) but 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 is to be installed
 software-center-aptdaemon-plugins : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ubuntu-system-service : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 unity : Depends: python:any
         Recommends: unity-scope-devhelp but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-guayadeque but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-calculator but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-zotero but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-gdrive but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-manpages but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-audacious but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-virtualbox but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-gmusicbrowser but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-colourlovers but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-clementine but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-gourmet but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-tomboy but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-openclipart but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-lens-photos but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-texdoc but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-lens-friends but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-yelp but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-scope-musique but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: hud but it is not going to be installed
 vim : Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Output of `apt-cache policy python`:

```
python: 
  Installed: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 
  Version table:
     2.7.5-5ubuntu3 0 
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages 
 *** 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0 
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

@ByteCommander: dpkg throws the below errors

```
sudo dpkg -i python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 179286 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking python (2.7.5-5ubuntu3) over (2.7.3-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python:
 python depends on python2.7 (>= 2.7.5-1~); however:
  Version of python2.7 on system is 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1.
 python depends on python-minimal (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3); however:
  Version of python-minimal on system is 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.
 python depends on libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3); however:
  Package libpython-stdlib is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python
```

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`: Produced the same errors as mentioned above.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` - Produced similar errors and in addition to that throws this below errors information.

```
dpkg: error processing package python-debtagshw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
 libpython-stdlib:i386
 python
 python-apport
 libpurple-bin
 software-center
 python-pexpect
 python-gdbm
 python-renderpm
 python-xkit
 python-lazr.uri
 python2.7
 landscape-client-ui-install
 python-pycurl
 python-appindicator
 python-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-louis
 ibus
 python-serial
 python-cups
 python-problem-report
 unity-control-center
 python-dateutil
 python-gnomekeyring
 compizconfig-settings-manager
 python-compizconfig
 python-gtk2
 python-gi-cairo
 python-gobject
 libgcj-common
 python-reportlab-accel
 python-pyinotify
 python-chardet
 python-xapian
 python-pam
 python-twisted-core
 python-gst0.10
 software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
 python-xdg
 ibus-table
 python-dirspec
 python-zeitgeist
 system-config-printer-common
 python-qt4
 python-wadllib
 python-virtkey
 python-markupsafe
 scons
 python-notify
 python-debtagshw
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Any help to resolve this issue is greatly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Did you run apt-get -f install as suggested?

Comment: Yes, but I still see the same errors.

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get install python`? If not, what is the output of `apt-cache policy python`?

Comment: Even `sudo apt-get install python` is throwing the same `unmet dependencies` error. And this is the output of apt-cache: `python:
  Installed: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2.7.5-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: You may try this: look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. All your previous install actions are listed there. Carefully try to revert every one of them until you have a working installation.

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-depends" install python=2.7.5-5ubuntu3`. Does that run correctly? And please don't forget to put "@ByteCommander" in your comments addressed at me, otherwise I won't get a notification. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I tried your suggestion, and I am seeing the same output that I see if I do `sudo apt-get -f install python`

Comment: Please try `apt-get download python` and then `dpkg -i HOWEVER_THE DOWNLOADED_PYTHON_FILE_IS_CALLED.deb`. What error messages do you get from dpkg, if any?

Comment: @ByteCommander: I have updated the question with the error messages that I get from dpkg.

Comment: @Jos: My history.log file has only one item 
`Start-Date: 2016-07-05  19:30:47
Commandline: apt-get -f upgrade` and then I see so many list of packages and libraries and at the end of the file `Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2016-07-05  20:03:30`

Comment: Your `history.log` is being zipped nightly by the `logrotate` process. For older messages, look in `history.log.1.gz`, `history.log.2.gz`, etc.

Comment: You say you're on 12.04 but you have some 14.04 packages, what is that about? Also if on i386 you do know that google-chrome no longer supports 32 bit.?

Comment: @doug: I was suspecting that about google chrome when I downloaded the deb it was giving me 64 bit file. I think that's where I did a mistake and still went ahead and tried installing it. Am not sure about 14.04 packages. But in this process to recover from this issue, I did `sudo do-release-upgrade` maybe that's the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Please run these commands:

```
mkdir tempdir
cd tempdir
apt-get download python python2.7 python-minimal libpython-stdlib
```

Then repeat the following two commands a few times:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Please report back whether you get error messages and add them to your question.

Comment: I still have same sort of errors I have updated the question with the errors that I noticed.